# How do I extract a single digit from a 3 digit whole number?

Tags: c, int

This isn't a homework question, I'm just curious. If I had a program that calculated a 3 digit number, say 123, how can I get just the "1"? I'm trying to print a message at the end that says "(The first digit) tells you...and (the last two digits) tell you..." But I'm not sure HOW to save or get that single digit. Any ideas? Is the a simpler way to do this other than using an array?Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use integer division by `100`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf( "%d\n", 123/100 ) ;

  return 0 ;
}
```

A more generalized approach would use subsequent rounds of modulus by `10` and integer division by `10` to remove the last digit until the number is less than `10`:

```
int num = 123 ;
while( num >= 10 )
{
    printf( "%d\n", num % 10 ) ;
    num = num / 10 ;
}
printf( "%d\n", num  ) ;
```

If you can display your digits in reverse order from last to first this method does not require any additional storage, if not you can store the results in an array.

Answer (score 1):

- Get the length of the number.
- Iterate & get each digit.

Here is a sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{
  int n = 123, i; char buffer [33];

  int len = n==0 ? 1 : floor(log10l(abs(n)))+1;

  for(i=n;len--; i=(int)(i/10)) buffer[len] = (i%10);

  printf("%d", buffer[0]);   // First Digit
  printf("%d", buffer[1]);   // Second Digit
  printf("%d", buffer[2]);   // Third Digit... so on

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it simple way , I mean, if you want to make it program for just one number e.g, 123 then the first example by Shafik is enough.

If you would like to take out the digits from the end then the second example of Shafik is good enough.

*Suggestions are welcome , if anybody sees improvement , thank you :)*

What about taking the digits out from the beginning, here is my different take on your question , I have taken the digits out from the beginning like this :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int di , i , num , pow = 1;
  setbuf ( stdout , NULL);
  printf ("enter the number of digits of the number\n");// specify at run time what will be the number of digits of the array.
  scanf ( "%d" , &di);
  int a[di];

  printf ("enter the %d digit number:\n",di);// 
  scanf ( "%d" , &num);//One thing is to be noted here that user can enter more digits than specified above , It is up to user to enter the specified digits , you can improve this program by making a check whether user enters the specified digits or not , better do it as exercise.
  while( di > 1 )
    {
    pow = pow * 10;
    di--;
    }

  i = 0;
  while ( num > 0)
    {
      a[i]=num/pow;
      num=num%pow;
      pow=pow/10;
      i++;
    }
  printf("the digits from the beginning are :\n"); 
  for(int j = 0 ; j < i ; j++)
    printf("%d\n",a[j]);
  return 0;
}
```

**Important**-- When using an array to store the digits if user enter more digits than specified then extra digits will printed as the first element of the array, As  I said you can improve this program further if you want and make a check on the user entering the number of digits , good luck :)

**NOTE**-- *This is just a different way of looking at a problem, both the solutions will eventually yield the same results. I just thought to put it this way.*

Comment: Also note one more point the VLA are possible from revision of the C standard i.e C99.