# How to print the first digits of a number in MIPS Assembly Programming?

Tags: assembly, mips, digits, mars-simulator

I am a beginner at programming in MIPS Assembly and I was wondering how I would print the first digit of a number after I have read it in.

```
.data
number_1: .word


.text
#read in first number
li $v0, 5
syscall
sw $v0, number_1

#print first digit
li $v0, 1
lw $a0, number_1
syscall

#end program
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

For example, if I entered 590, I would only want to print '5'.  In addition how would I print the next two numbers seperately?

Using the above code, it only prints the whole number I entered: 590
I have tried lb, instead of lw, but it prints '78' and I'm guessing that number is in hex or another base.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How would you do it in some other language or pseudocode?

Answer (score 1):

For this number you have, you need to obtain the number mod 10 or mod 100 for 2nd and 3rd digits respectively. 
The modulo is your next digit, and you can repeat this until the result of division is 0. This assuming you're not working with floating point numbers.

My recommendation for MIPS assembly is always to have a general solution in a higher level language such as C, here is a solution similar to the one I outlined above:

```
int n = 590 ;
while( n >= 10 )
{
    printf( "%d\n", n % 10 ) ;
    n = n / 10 ;
}
printf( "%d\n", n ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Numbers are stored in memory in hex. What you want is the first digits in decimal, which has to be calculated. For a 3 digit number, integer division by 100 would get you your result. General solutions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690360/how-do-i-extract-a-single-digit-from-a-3-digit-whole-number).

Comment: Integers are stored in memory in binary.  Hex is just a convenient human-readable way of grouping 4-bit chunks of binary into alphanumeric characters, and the conversion only happens inside the debugger.